# Third-order ODE with NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I would like to use `NDSolve` to draw the integral curve of a third-order ODE

```
s = NDSolve[{y'''[x] - x y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 1}, y, {x, -4, 4}]
```

but it does not seem possible.

Comment: Your code worked for me at Mma 10.0.2, win7.

Comment: What went wrong? Did you get any error messages? What version of _Mathematica_ are you running and on what system?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Finally it works...

Answer (score 1):

I'm running V10.0.2 on OS X 10.6.8. Your code works fine of my system.

```
s = NDSolve[{y'''[x] - x y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, y''[0] == 1}, y, {x, -4, 4}];
Plot[s[[1, 1, 2]][x], {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image: plot]